Microsoft Fabric REST API - How to call REST API without granting access to Workspace
I am using an App Registration to authenticate to the Microsoft Fabric REST API through a Python script.
To do this, I followed the steps below:

I created an Application;

I created a certificate and secrets;

I granted API permissions to the Fabric\PowerBI Endpoints;

I created a User Group and included the Application as a member;

I enabled the Administration API in Microsoft Fabric;

I granted access to the Workspace for the Application;

I tested authentication via REST API in a Notebook;


The tests in the notebook were completed successfully. In other words, I was able to authenticate to the Fabric REST API without any problems.
My question is: is there any way to avoid having to grant access to the Workspaces for the Application?
I would like to run the Python code that uses the Fabric REST API Endpoints without having to grant access to the Workspaces.
I tried to authenticate to the Microsoft Fabric REST API without gaining access to Workspace

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I would like to know if it is possible to use a Registered Application to make a call to a Fabric REST API EndPoint without the need for this Registered Application to be a member of a Workspace.

it's not possible!
Granting access to the workspaces is necessary for the application to interact with the Fabric REST API. This is because the API permissions and access controls are designed to ensure secure and controlled access to the data and resources within the workspaces.
One potential workaround could be to use service principal authentication for read-only admin APIs, which might reduce the need for direct workspace access in some scenarios.
